# Calling a web service from within PHP asyncronously

Tags: php, web-services, asynchronous, gsoap

How to do it? I need to call a web service from within a PHP which is not going to be executed by apache asynchronously. What's your suggestion? Is it better to write a C or C++ code for it instead of PHP? Since NuSoap is already installed, I prefer to avoid getting involved with gSoap. With NuSoap, I may call the other server's web service with less effort. I need a daemon to poll the web service call and hold the returned data as cache on the first server.

You may ask why async call? It's because the second server may not be only one. The response from the second servers may take time to receive, and during this time I prefer to send request to other servers to have parallel responses. This helps me the receives all responses in a shorter time.

**Update:**

A System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol object is used to communicate with the web services on the server side which is handled by NuSoap. Requests are targeted the main server or federated servers. In the latter situation, they're routed via the main server. We currently use the following mechanism to call the web services located on the federated servers:

```
$SoapClient = GetSoapClient($ServerId, $SessionId);
$result = $SoapClient->call(
    "WebServiceName",
    array(
        'Parameter1' => $Value1,
        'Parameter2' => $Value2,
        ...
    )
);
```

while the GetSoapClient function defines as:

```
function GetSoapClient($ServerId, $LocalSessionId)
{
    try
    {
        $srv = dbFetchOne("SELECT * FROM Servers WHERE id = ".intval($ServerId));
        $wsdlUrl = "http://".$srv['IP'].":".$srv['Port']."/webService.php?wsdl";
        $cache = new wsdlcache('/tmp');
        $wsdl = $cache->get($wsdlUrl);
        if (is_null($wsdl))
        {
            $wsdl = new wsdl($wsdlUrl);
            if ($wsdl && $wsdl->getError() === false)
                $cache->put($wsdl);
        }
        $client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true, '', '', '', '');
        $err = $client->getError();
        if ($err)
        {
            error_log("Constructor error".$err);
        }
        $client->requestHeaders = array('LocalSessionId' => $LocalSessionId);
        $client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
        $client->decode_utf8 = false;
        return $client;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

According to this, what can be the shortest way and the best method for implementing what i ask?
Thanks for your attention.

PS. server-side codes are in PHP.

Comment: You might want to take a glance at [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/) Sounds like what you could be looking for.

Comment: I would recommend using NodeJs for API. I found it easier and faster way to develop REST API using Node Express.

Comment: thank you. so i should learn ReactPHP, Nodejs and REST API. they're completely new terms for me.

Comment: [ReactPHP](https://github.com/reactphp/http-client) and [Amp](https://github.com/amphp/artax) both offer async HTTP clients for PHP. NodeJS obviously has its own client(s). If you're using SOAP, you can just keep that, but send the actual HTTP request over one of those clients instead of whatever client you're currently using.

Comment: I updated the question for including more detailed description.